# Ubuntu Software displays only Editors' Picks

Tags: software-center

And the Explore button does not work.  Similar and same questions asked in the past have never resulted in a solution.  The problem seems to go away, eventually, to everyone's satisfaction but without know what caused it or how to fix it sooner than "eventually".

Using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: What happens if you close the gui and `sudo killall snap-store` then re-launch it? It might take a while to load, because it re-loads all the store data and only shows it once it's all loaded.

Comment: @popey  --  Many thanks for your suggestion but so far I didn't get a chance to try it.  Miraculously, the problem has disappeared (like it often does) and the app now displays all the categories, besides Editor's Picks, and loads the information about any category fairly quickly.  I will certainly try your suggestion next time it happens, though, as it surely will happen again.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I'd like to put a tick beside Popey's answer. It worked well. Thank you Hal_v

Answer (score 1):

From **popey's comment**: `Sudo killall snap-store` works like a charm, and it was super fast. When I tried to reopen the Ubuntu software app, it took a second to update and then opened absolutely perfectly.  Great solution.  It has been glitchy ever since I started using Ubuntu.  Hopefully a permanent fix will be discovered.